# How to open text files with CarrierWave and load content to textarea. (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I currently have a Ruby on Rails project that has CarrierWave running on it.  The project allows uploading of text files.

I'm stumped, though.

How can I open these files and put their text content into an HTML textarea element?

Comment: We'll probably need a few more details about your setup before anyone can help.  You're using CarrierWave to handle uploads, but where are the uploads going?  What kinds of files are being uploaded?  Under what circumstances do you want to put an uploaded file into a textarea?  Why not use a database instead of uploaded files?

Comment: Right now the uploaded files are going into the default storage directory for CarrierWave (localhost:3000/uploads/...).  Files that are being uploaded include .html, .java, .css, .js, etc.  Just text files that can be used for programming code.  The circumstance in which the file is put into a textarea: there will be a list of files in a select box, a file will be selected, a button will be pushed, and then the text will be loaded into the textarea.  This is an application for project collaboration. Users will upload code files that will be able to be edited by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was very simple.  I used jQuery's ajax method "get()".  This method accepts a URL to a file (text file in this case) and then does some action.  So, for a textarea, this action would include setting the textarea's val to the data the get() method retrieves.